# Using gawk to prepend the system hostname (without newline) to a string

Tags: shell, awk, gawk

I'm trying to use gawk to prepend the system hostname to a string. I'm away I can do something like this:

```
interesting_command.sh|gawk 'print system("hostname") "\t" $0'
```

But that ends up printing:

```
hostname.example.com
    Line 1 text
hostname.example.com
    Line 2 text
```

etc.

Ideally, I'm looking for the output of `hostname` but with any newlines or whitespace 
characters stripped.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your command gives me a syntax error. After adding the missing curly braces, I get the hostname on alternate lines as you show in your example output, but on the lines with data from the shell script, I get 0 as the first character because that's the return value of the `system()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
echo "1
2
3" |awk 'BEGIN{"hostname" | getline hstnm ; }; {print hstnm "\t" $0}'
myhost       1
myhost       2
myhost       3
```

The plan here is to capture the output of hostname into a var (hstnm) using `getline`, and then use the variable to print the value as you need it. I half expected to to include a `sub(/\n$/, "", hstnm)` as part of the BEGIN statement, but as you see it's not necessary.

IHTH.